# how to transfer a collection of files based on criteria in data frame in the most efficient way

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe, coding-efficiency

Probably the subject I chose is not a good subject. but Im going to explain very clearly. my purpose is to come up with the most efficient way as the number of files is very big and it may take long time.

I have a folder which contains a lot of files(300K). these files have names. the pattern in their name is like this:

```
09060083_1542296310_2_CON_ENT-Floor-Practice_2015-09-25-false_MRB3738.txt
```

in the name of this file one things matter for me:

1. `09060083` which I extract simply

I also have a data frame. my data frame looks like this:

```
            Clinic Number  6month
1              09060083     1
2              494383       4
13             494383       4
14             494383       1
17             494382       9
21             494382       4
25             494383       4
28             494383       4
29             994381       5
30             994383      10
```

Clinic number is the same as from character 1 to 8 of the file name. Now I want to transfer some of the files to another folders based on some criteria.

my folder name is based on `6month column` in data frame. so I have 10 folder name 1 2 3... 10.

**My simple method for doing this** is that to extract character 1 to 8 of the file name, then compare with `Clinic Number column` in the data frame, then if they were the same transfer to the folder with corresponding name of `6month column` of that row.

But I guess it will take long time. I m looking for the most efficient way to do it. with my approach its almost awefull as it needs to loop throughth whole data frame for every single file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find duplicate clinic entries and then move the corresponding files to the respective folder.

e.g. if your df is like

```
Clinic_Num  6month Filename
09060083     1     09060083_blah
494383       4     494383_blah1
494383       4     494383_blah2
494383       1     494383_blah3
```

Select all duplicate rows by:

```
df_to_be_moved = df[df.duplicated(subset='Clinic_Num')]
```

Now, your df_to_moved will be like:

```
Clinic_Num  6month Filename
494383       4     494383_blah2
494383       1     494383_blah3
```

Now you can select rows based on your destination folder and get a list of filepath for that folder and move them.

```
import os, shutil
BASE_PATH = "C:\Users\M193053\Documents\"

for idx in range(1,11):  # folder name
    folder_name = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "folder_"+str(idx))
    os.makedirs(folder_name, exist_ok=True)
    matches = df_to_be_moved[df_to_be_moved['6month']==idx].Filename.tolist()
    matches = [os.path.join(BASE_PATH, filename) for filename in matches]
    for file in matches:
        shutil.move(file, folder_name)
```

Comment: your approach is awesome, except that I need to add something in the first of each element of matches list. because it is only name of the file, so I need to add the full path to be able to move

Comment: Also where are you making the folders?

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi `os.makedirs()` will take care of that.

Comment: `os.makedirs("folder_"+str(idx))` will take care of creating the folders one for each number from 1 to 10. Of course, we need to use absolute path to make the code work as per requirement. Also, you can change folder names as needed.

Comment: updated the code to specify a base path. You can specify it as your project root folder. All the files will be searched and new folders will be created within that folder.

Comment: I am ok with this folder_name = os.makedirs(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "folder_"+str(idx)))   but I did not know how the base path will be added to the filename in the matches list. I m gonna try it now with a small data then let you know, thanks :)

Comment: It seems shutil.move or shutil.copy wont accept list as the first argument , I will be happy if you have any other idea update it

Comment: I do not know why i did not pay attention. using df.duplicated is not correct because it only keeps the duplicated rows, I did want to keep both duplicate and unique ones . but in duplicate only one distict row so I think this answer should be updated in case do not lead someone incorrectly :)

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi can you explain what do you mean by "in duplicate only one distinct row"?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the line "extract character 1 to 8 of the file name,  then compare with Clinic Number column in the data frame, then if they were the same transfer to the folder with corresponding name of 6month column of that row". Do you need all the files to be transferred just based on their corresponding `6month` column?